# Focusing on text cursor in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-jetpack

does anyone know how I am able to get focus on a text cursor in a textfield? I am having an issue with resizing scrollable text fields, so I want to request focus to on the cursor instead.